# How can I create a codepage under Windows?

Tags: encoding, codepages

I want to create a codepage under Windows, but I do not where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can I ask what for?

Comment: To do some test about encoding such as converting character between different codecs.

Comment: You can't, at least not in any official way. You might try reverse-engineer an existing C_<number>.NLS file (for instance C_1250.NLS is the 1250 encoder). They are in fact DLLs and are in the system folder. But it is (of course) not legal, you can't redistribute the result, and so on (it might also depend where you are in the world :-)